# WordProcessingML. How do I assign background color to text?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-automation, wordprocessingml

I have code that creates document with several paragraphs with different text-color for some words. Something like:

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create("some-file-name", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    // Add a new main document part. 
    var mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();                                
    mainPart.Document = new Document();
    var body = new Body();

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    var run = new Run();
    ...
    // append bold text 
    run.AppendChild(new RunProperties {Bold = new Bold(), });
    run.AppendChild(new Text("some-text"));
    ...
    // append red text 
    run.AppendChild(new RunProperties
             { Color = new Color {Val = "FF0000"}});
    run.AppendChild(new Text("some-text"));
```

But I haven't found a way how to add text with colored background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer myself:

Background is **Highlight** property:

```
// yellow background sample 
run.AppendChild(new RunProperties { Highlight = new Highlight { Val = HighlightColorValues.Yellow } });
run.AppendChild(new Text("some-text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to set the [w:shd property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.shading%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in the run properties. I was using docx4j, but the principal is the same.